# JavaScript function doesnt execute all of the code in the function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, http, next.js

I have a function that makes a PUT request to a server, then after its comeplete. It is supposed to run another piece of code, but it never executes.

```
  const createNewWatchlist = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios({
        url: `http://localhost:5000/api/users/${session?.id}/addwatchlist`,
        method: "PUT",
        data: {
          watchlistName: watchlistName,
          coins: {
            coin: {
              coinID: coinID,
            },
          },
        },
      });
      setPopUp(true);  // Code here & down does not execute
      console.log(popUp);
      console.log(`${watchlistName} created!`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

I have a similar function that does work:

```
  const addCoinToWatchlist = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios({
        url: `http://localhost:5000/api/users/${session?.id}/addcointowatchlist`,
        method: "PUT",
        data: {
          watchlistName: selectWatchlist,
          coinID: coinID,
        },
      });
      setSuccessMessage(true);
      console.log(successMessage);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

Whats the reason the first function only partially works?

Comment: Do you see an error in the console?

Comment: no, the code posts the watchlist, but does nothing after that.

Comment: Is the PUT request completing? Throwing an error? What debugging have you done? I see no reason why the entire function wouldn't execute other than an unhandled exception being thrown.

Comment: yes the put request works

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Try to compare executions of that two functions, maybe you execute without `await` or without `.then(...)`.